# How to check the checkboxes on AJAX reload

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I added some checkboxes on AJAX response and everything is fine, but these checkboxes cannot be checked. I know the reason, but don't know how to fix it.
I tried

```
document.on(),live(), delegate()
```

but it is still not working.

**JS part**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#select').change(function(){
        console.log($('#select').val());
        $.ajax({
               type : "GET",
               url : "orderList/filter",
               data : {
                   "status": $('#select').val()
               },
               dataType : 'html',
               success : function(data) {
                    $("tbody").html(data);
               },
               error : function(e) {
                   console.log("ERROR: ", e);
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

**JSP part**

```
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" class="flat checkMei" 
           name="order_id"                                                              
           value="${item.id}">
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Corrected the syntax and the code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('#checkBox').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: It is not right, my friend. I need to use these checkbox normally, They are ok before i reload data by ajax. But after loading new html they cant be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ajaxComplete(function().

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

See more [here.](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 $('#checkBox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i dont need to set them checked, i need to use them normally, they cant be use after re-loading by ajax